# Create array from MySQL results, and add new items

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, pdo

I've got a MySQL search query outputting to an array:

```
$result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

What I'd like to be able to is add further keys/values to each array item.

So at the moment it outputs:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(7) {
    ["organisation"]=>
    string(32) "7a5fddaceecec75c9a13cb329f6b4b15"
    ["date_created"]=>
    string(10) "2017-08-04"
  }
}
```

I'd like it also to include this on the end of the array:

```
'name' => getName($result['name'];
```

I assume I do that with array_push and a while loop? I just can't figure out how.

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to include `'name' => getName($result['name']);` at the end of every array or just first array?

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to use array_push() to insert a "$key" => "$value" pair into an array, it can be done using the following:

```
$data[$key] = $value;
```

It is not necessary to use array_push.

Comment: Thanks - how can I insert that in to each array item though? Wouldn't I need to create a while loop for each array item?

Comment: foreach($arr as $item){
 $item['name'] = $value;

Comment: Sorry - I'm still new at this. I don't think I'm understanding. The array is four items long and I want to add a fifth that uses the data of one of the items. So instead of `{ 'name' => 'john', 'id' => '2' } { 'name' => 'jack', 'id' => '5' }` I could take add another which `'address' => function($arr['id'])` inside each item.

Comment: sorry, im not complete sure what you want to do

Comment: This is the array now: `array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["hash"]=>
    string(32) "0d06"
    ["organisation"]=>
    string(32) "7a5fdd"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["hash"]=>
    string(32) "cba33"
    ["organisation"]=>
    string(32) "7a5fdd"
  }
}`. I'd like to grab the $array['organisation'] in each item, run it through a function I built, e.g. `function($array['organisation'])`, and add it back to the array so it is  `array(3) {
    ["hash"]=>
    string(32) "cba33"
    ["organisation"]=>
    string(32) "7a5fd"
    ["address"]=>
    string(32) "jlkjlkjasd"
  }`

Comment: So the input of the function is the organisation and the output is the address?

Comment: Yep. And I just want to add it as another item in the same array... and do it for each of the eg 10 items in the array

Comment: `foreach($arr as $item){
 $address = function($item[organisation])
 item['address'] = $address;
}`